# Chrome Latest version will not clear cookies ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, google-chrome, cookies, webforms

I have an ASP.NET web form application using 4.5.2 framework. Chrome's latest update seems to eliminated the ability for my application to clear the cookies. I know the SameSite attribute can be added to framework versions 4.7.2 and greater but I am not having any luck finding anything that works for older versions. Does anyone have a simple solution to bring back clearing cookies so my application will work correctly? What are my options around this? I've tried adding rewrite rules in my config, but didnt have any luck with that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Could you post your current code in your question

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio 17 or 19 after you have enabled debugging of Web Apps directly on browser (as image shows from Settings→Debug→General→ Enable debugging of Javascript on browsers …… of ASP.Net pages)  then you when select Chrome as Browser to test your Web-App ASP.NET the only thing to do every time you need to restart without cookies o browser history related to your Web-App is:
Right click on Refresh arrow → “Clear Cache and restart/reload manually” (as image below shows)

[image]